# Popup message overriding the current browser page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, popup, window

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I would like to show a block (that is, something like a popup message - I think it should be a HTML `div` tag...) in the middle of a page without open a new page.

For example, clicking a link in a page it should appear overriding the current browser page and should have a fixed width. In few words, I would like to implement something as a Facebook "generic dialog popup".

**How can I implement that? How I must state HTML and CSS?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many, many solutions to modal dialogs in JS.

For example:

- http://ssssnakes.com/smoke/
- http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/
- http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/